# 週次データを日次に格納する方法

Tags: python, pandas

df1は、indexが2015-01-04,2015-01-05,2015-01-06のように日次で入っています。
df2は、indexが2015-01-04,2015-01-11,2015-01-18のように週次で入っています。

df2のindexをdf1に揃え、df2の2015-01-04と同じ値が2015-01-04,01-05,01-06,01-07、、の一週間に入るようにするには、どのようにコードを書けばよいのでしょうか。

分かる方いらっしゃいましたら、ご教授よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

あんまりかっこよくないですが、以下でどうでしょうか。

```
for index in df2.index:
    df1[(df1.index >= index) & (df1.index < index+pd.Timedelta(days=7))]=df2.ix[index,:][0]
```